# Xamarin Forms access denied when writing to file with FileStream

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, access-denied

I'm trying to append a string to a text file located within a .NET shared project while running the app on a real Android device (Android 8.0 - API 26), but I'm getting this runtime error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
"/Namespace.Folder.FileName.txt" is denied.
```

The code causing the error:

```
string filename= "Namespace.Folder.FileName.txt";
FileStream fs = null; fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs); sw.Write(text)
```

I have both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION checked under Android permissions and the text file's build action is set to Embedded Resource.
I've tried using System.IO.File and it's working fine, but this way I don't know how not to overwrite the text file

```
var documentsPath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
```

I guess my question is what's the best way to store text in a text file located within the shared project without overwriting it?

Comment: I think you are misunderstand some things here. "I have both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION checked" these are for accessing the users GPS location, so this is not going to help you here. You need to lookup the filesystem permissions.

Comment: My bad, WriteExternalStorage is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem, I wasn't passing in the root folder to the writer and reader.
Working code:

Load:

```
var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return content;
        }
```

Write:

```
var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(text);
        }
```