# I cannot get file handling to work and have followed all the posts

Tags: forms, xamarin, file-io

I added a text file via As you can see from my code I implemented their code. On running, it gets System.AggregateException with message "access denied to path"

I read the posts:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64887/how-to-read-write-files

Here is my code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadTxt
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {


        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



                Label l = new Label()
                {
                    Text = ReadTextLine().Result
                };
                StackLayout s = new StackLayout();
                s.Children.Add(l);
            Content = new ScrollView { Content = s };

            async Task<string> ReadTextLine()
            {
                var backingFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TextFile1.txt");
                using (var writer = File.CreateText(backingFile))
                {
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync("Updated text");
                }

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(backingFile, true))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                    {

                    }


                    return line;
                }
            }
        } } }
```

Comment: are you testing this on iOS or Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General, the easier way to handle file is using those methods in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#saving-and-loading-files), something like:

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label l = new Label()
        {
        };
        StackLayout s = new StackLayout();
        s.Children.Add(l);
        Content = new ScrollView { Content = s };

        var backingFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TextFile1.txt");

        File.WriteAllText(backingFile, "updatedText");
        string text = File.ReadAllText(backingFile);

        l.Text = text;
    }
```

When debugging your code, it seems you are updating the text in a `sub thread` which is not allowed both in `iOS` and `Android`. Also, I don't think the while statement is necessary while reading the text from the file. I modified your code like below and it works on my side:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Label l = new Label()
    {
    };
    StackLayout s = new StackLayout();
    s.Children.Add(l);
    Content = new ScrollView { Content = s };

    ReadTextLine();

    async void ReadTextLine()
    {
        var backingFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TextFile1.txt");
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(backingFile))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("Updated text");
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(backingFile, true))
        {
            string line;

            line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                l.Text = line;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I don't add permissions and it works on Android Q emulator and iOS 13 simulator. You can try to add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to `AndroidManifest.xml` to ask for permissions in Android project as `Юра Кириченко` mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it on UWP with the same error. I will try ANdroid next and report back.

Comment: Works on Android. Thank you

Comment: @RichardOsborne Can you please mark this answer if it helps you:).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permissions to Android.Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check this answer. Maybe it will help you
[Xamarin Forms access denied when writing to file with FileStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765481/xamarin-forms-access-denied-when-writing-to-file-with-filestream)